# AzCopy - how to specify metadata when copying a file to a blob storage

Tags: metadata, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm trying to upload a file to an Azure Blob storage using AzCopy, but I want to include metadata.
According to the documentation, "AzCopy copy" has a metadata parameter where I have to provide key/value pairs as a string.
How has this string to be formatted? I can't get it to work and don't find any examples...

`AzCopy.exe copy .\testfile2.txt "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/upload/testfile4.txt?sastoken" --metadata ?what_here?`

Thanks!

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string should be in this format: `--metadata "name=ivan"`.

If you want to add multi metadata, use this format: `--metadata "name=ivan;city=tokyo"`

This is the command I'm using, and the version of azcopy is `10.3.4` :

```
azcopy copy "file_path" "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test1/aaa1.txt?sasToken" --metadata "name=ivan"
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ivan! This is probably the only format I didn't try. Would be nice if the documentation had an Example.

Comment: Yah, only problem seems to be that azcopy has the audacity to change the capitalization of the key, changing name to Name